# Angular Update Error fetching metadata for '@angular/core': Invalid URL: 127.0.0.1:4200

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I'm getting this error when trying to update my angular project from version 9.1 to 10. Even when I try to update another project from angular 10 to 11 getting the same error.

[image]

Have you ever faced this issue? What could be the problem? How can I solve the problem?

```
Your global Angular CLI version (10.1.7) is greater than your local
version (9.1.12). The local Angular CLI version is used.

To disable this warning use "ng config -g cli.warnings.versionMismatch false".
The installed local Angular CLI version is older than the latest stable 
version.
Installing a temporary version to perform the update.
Installing packages for tooling via npm.
Installed packages for tooling via npm.
Using package manager: 'npm'
Collecting installed dependencies...
Found 40 dependencies.
Fetching dependency metadata from registry...
Error fetching metadata for '@angular/core': Invalid URL: 127.0.0.1:4200
```

Comment: It seems that you have a routing problem on you PC. The call for the actual service on the internet is replaced by your localhost. Restart your computer an try again.

Comment: I restarted my computer. It still not working

Answer (score 0):

im not sure which causes this issue but i tried these and it successfully updated to angular 10:

1. login to artifactory
2. update the .npmrc file: _auth, email
3. run `npx @angular/cli@10 update @angular/core@10 @angular/cli@10` again